# Create nested JSON arrays using FOR JSON PATH from stored procedure

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table as shown below and need to return data in JSON format to Azure Logic App.

[image]

Adding table scripts below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData]
(
    [StudentID] [int] NULL,
    [subject] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [result] [varchar](10) NULL
) 
GO
```

And following is the test data.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [subject], [result]) 
VALUES (506995, N'PHYSICS', N'Pass')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [subject], [result]) 
VALUES (506995, N'CHEMISTRY', N'Fail')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [subject], [result]) 
VALUES (506996, N'PHYSICS', N'Pass')
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [subject], [result]) 
VALUES (506996, N'BIOLOGY', N'Pass' )
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TempStudentJsonData] ([StudentID], [subject], [result]) 
VALUES (506997, N'MATH', N'Pass')
GO
```

From this table, I want to generate a JSON as shown below

```
[
        {
            "506995": [
                {
                    "subject": "Physics",
                    "result": "Pass"
                },
                 {
                    "subject": "Chemistry",
                    "result": "Fail"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "506996" : [
                {
                    "subject": "Physics",
                    "reason": "Pass"
                },
                {
                    "subject": "Biology",
                    "reason": "Pass"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "506997" : [
                {
                    "subject": "Math",
                    "reason": "Pass"
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

How can we achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: That's nesting, not a GROUP BY operation.

Comment: Using dynamic property names `"506995"`, `"506996"` and `"506997"` like that is just awful. Is that an actual business requirement or just something you wanted to do?

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured out. Not suggestible and straightforward to use dynamic property names. Will be implementing PARENT / CHILD for this.
But still, is this doable? dynamic property names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support dynamic keys, nor does it support `JSON_AGG` (creating a bare JSON array). So you need to build some of it yourself using `STRING_AGG`

```sql
SELECT '[' + STRING_AGG(sjd.json, ',') + ']'
FROM (
    SELECT
      json =
      CONCAT(
        '{"',
        sjd.StudentID,
        '":[',
        STRING_AGG(j.json, ','),
        ']}'
      )
    FROM TempStudentJsonData sjd
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT
          sjd.subject,
          sjd.result
        FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
    ) j(json)
    GROUP BY
      sjd.StudentID
) sjd;
```

Note that the benefit of this version over correlated self-joins is that you only scan the table once

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e44df940b0488b468e7f15cd785a6009)

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "506995": [
      {
        "subject": "PHYSICS",
        "result": "Pass"
      },
      {
        "subject": "CHEMISTRY",
        "result": "Fail"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "506996": [
      {
        "subject": "PHYSICS",
        "result": "Pass"
      },
      {
        "subject": "BIOLOGY",
        "result": "Pass"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "506997": [
      {
        "subject": "MATH",
        "result": "Pass"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: can we parse this string to JSON Object as when returning this in output parameter in Logic app, its appending backslash' \'  with all output values? and also adding extra quotes at the start and end. or can we somehow remove these escaping characters?

Tried, OPENJSON but didn't able to. 

**"[{\"506997\":[{\"subject\":\"Physics\",\"result\":\"Pass\"}**

Comment: There is no JSON object in SQL Server, it's always `nvarchar(max)`. The extra escaping is caused because Logic understands it as a string. You need to parse it into an object once you get it into your app, I suggest you create a different question for that.

Comment: should we parse this string and pass the JSON object to the logic app or (not sure) we can parse it in the Logic App itself.

Comment: In SQL Server there is nothing to parse. JSON is just a string. You need to parse it in the app.

Comment: This is by default sorting it by ascending order by StudentID.
How can we use order by in it, if we want to order it or rather keep the same sequence as we have in the table? or order it by any other table column.

Comment: `STRING_AGG(sjd.json, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY someColumn)` note that the column has to be available at that level of aggregation